# use @Activate annotation in OSGI in Karaf

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf

I am trying to have a function in my brand new bundle that is triggered once when the Apache Karaf container is started.

The main class in the Bundle looks like this:

```
@Component(service = BrandNewBundle.class)
public class BrandNewBundle {

    ....
    @Activate
    protected void activate(ComponentContext myComponentContext) {
        LOG.info("Brand new bundle started.");
    }
}
```

In the karaf console I see the bundle status as `Active`. But in the logs, I don't see the message that I have tried to log.

Some information:

- It's a Maven build
- `osgi.cmpn` and `slf4j-api` are my dependencies in `pom.xml`, and nothing else so far.
- There is no `bnd.bnd` file in this

I have read the [`Apache Felix Service Component Runtime (SCR)`](https://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-service-component-runtime.html) page. Unlike what it mentioned there, my `OSGI-INF/....xml` is Autogenerated. I don't know how to debug further.

To sum up, the question is, how to actually trigger my `activate` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Component` annotation has to have an `immediate=true` as well. I added that, and the `activate()` function was triggered on the karaf start.

```
@Component(
    immediate=tue,
    service = BrandNewBundle.class
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be a classic issue in karaf. You need to install the scr feature.

```
feature:install scr
```